# AWS php5.4 cant connect to RDS

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I recently created a new SSD (t2.small) standard linux box on AWS and installed 
`php -v` 
`PHP 5.4.30 (cli) (built: Jul  9 2014 21:40:37)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies`
 

with

`/usr/sbin/httpd -v` 
`Server version: Apache/2.4.9 (Amazon)
Server built:   Apr  1 2014 05:31:18`

when I 
`php -m | grep mysqli`
it returns 
`mysqli`

However when i try conncting to `RDS`, this test does not return anything, i get a spinner and it times out.  Also nothing returns to php log

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("amazonrds", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
```

RDS security group is ok, i can connect using `MySql Workbench`.

How can i connect PHP to RDS?
thank you

**fixed** i had to add the public ip in the field `CIDR/IP of your current machine`

Comment: Have you set up proper access policies to your RDS instance from the EC2 instance? Can you show what your RDS security group definition looks like?

Comment: @MikeBrant The instance im connecting from was a newer SSD vs older magnetic.  The security group from RDS only shows security groups from the older magnetic volumes.  Do you think i need a different version of RDS to connect to?

Comment: NOt a different verion of RDS, but you will need to have whatever security group your EC2 is listed in be included in the RDS security group profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the OP added int the question, the answer is:

To add the public IP in the field CIDR/IP of your current machine

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with EC2 which installed PHP5.

I have two servers.

servers1: PHP 7.4

From EC2 1 I run command: `nc -zv rds_endpoint 3306`
Result: `Connection to rds_endpoint 3306 port [tcp/mysql] succeeded!`

I wrote a PHP code and connect to RDS and it works fine.

servers2: PHP 5.3

From servers2 I run command: `nc -zv rds_endpoint 3306`
Result: `Connection to rds_endpoint 3306 port [tcp/mysql] succeeded!`
I tried the command: `mysql - h rds_endpoint -u dbuser -p dbpass`. The result is a successful connection.

I wrote the same PHP code with servers1 to connect, but it can't connect to RDS.

This is the issue on aws forums.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=115970

Anything any update for this case?